# Fabric: Crashlytics upload tombstone with crash android?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

Android generates tombstone files with it's crashes. I'd like to upload these with the crash report when crashlytics reports.

Is there a way to upload your tombstone file from a crash with crashlytics when your application crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul from Crashlytics here. This currently isn't built out in Fabric, but it's great to know you'd like to see it added in!

Comment: Is this answer still current?